# Floating items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, floating

How can I create a control container where every item (control) behaves like a Floating DIV (in HTML), like this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur_EDX8bMGo&feature=youtu.be) (considering that each folder is a control)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the WrapPanel class. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx)

It has the functionality you are looking for.

> Positions child elements in sequential position from left to right, breaking content to the next line at the edge of the containing box. Subsequent ordering happens sequentially from top to bottom or from right to left, depending on the value of the Orientation property.